# How does a New Game + differ from a standard New Game?

Tags: bravely-default

I've completed my first game of Bravely Default, and now I have the option to start a New Game +. If I choose a New Game +, what do I get to keep from my standard game? Are there any new areas? Are there any plot differences?

Comment: Doesn't the game give you a list of options of what you want to be transferred over to the new game+ when you start one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're allowed to pick and choose what to bring over. Each one is a toggle.

- Jobs / job levels
- Your inventory
- Levels
- Pg
- Genomes
- Norende villagers
- Norende shops
- D's journal
- Special moves
- Friends
- Guests
- Play time

Comment: Is there any change in plot? Access to any new areas?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of.